# Mersenne Twister - Out of range exception

Tags: vb.net, exception, mersenne-twister

In a VB.NET implementation of the Mersenne Twister, I am getting an out-of-range exception, which is being thrown periodically (error image screenshot below):

```
         Private Shared mt(312 - 1) As ULong
         Private Shared mti As ULong = 312 + 1


         Private Function genrand64_int64() As ULong
            On Error GoTo errhandler

            Dim i As Long
            Dim x As ULong
            Static mag01() As ULong = {0UL, MATRIX_A}

            If mti >= NN Then ' generate NN words at one time

                ' if init_genrand64() has not been called, 
                ' a default initial seed is used     
                If mti = NN + 1 Then
                    init_genrand64(5489UL)
                End If

                i = 0
                Do While i < NN - MM
                    x = (mt(i) And UM) Or (mt(i + 1) And LM)
                    mt(i) = mt(i + MM) Xor (x >> 1) Xor mag01(CInt(x And 1UL))
                    i += 1
                Loop
                Do While i < NN - 1
                    x = (mt(i) And UM) Or (mt(i + 1) And LM)
                    mt(i) = mt(i + (MM - NN)) Xor (x >> 1) Xor mag01(CInt(x And 1UL))
                    i += 1
                Loop
                x = (mt(NN - 1) And UM) Or (mt(0) And LM)
                mt(NN - 1) = mt(MM - 1) Xor (x >> 1) Xor mag01(CInt(x And 1UL))

                mti = 0
            End If

            x = mt(mti)   '<<<<<<<<<<<HERE<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            mti += 1

            x = x Xor (x >> 29) And &H5555555555555555UL
            x = x Xor (x << 17) And &H71D67FFFEDA60000UL
            x = x Xor (x << 37) And &HFFF7EEE000000000UL
            x = x Xor (x >> 43)

            Return x
         End Function
```

Specifically, the exception is as follows:

[image]

Note that the mt() vector checks out OK with 312 elements, and during the exception the index value of mti=42, 86, or 212, well within the range of 312.  Is the value of x too large?

The init is:

```
   Sub init_genrand64(ByVal seed As ULong)
     mt(0) = seed
     For mti = 1 To NN - 1
       mt(mti) = (6364136223846793005UL * (mt(mti - 1) Xor (mt(mti - 1) >> 62)) + mti)
     Next mti
   End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a certain seed and iteration it chokes on?  That looks somewhat like my implementation (whose output matches that of 2 others), but there are some differences.

Comment: I use init_array, so isn't that a random seed?   I haven't looked at integer seeds(?)

Comment: What did you use as a source?  The tempering portion at the end is different than the [official source](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/MT2002/CODES/mt19937ar.c)  That `5489UL` in init_genrand64 is the default seed but you can use others.  There are also lists of thousands of MT values (somewhere) for a given seed than you can use to verify your implementation - did you?

Comment: There is also a NuGet package: MathNet which includes MT.  There was a bug but I reported it and they did fix it - oddly, I was trying to use theirs to validate mine.

Comment: If the NuGet package is not in VB.NET then it would exceed my need for rapid implementation.   I can quickly convert from C++ and C# to VB.NET, but you never have the author's guarantee that it works.

Comment: Recall, the code throws the exception much earlier than generating thousands of random variates.   So there is a hang somewhere(?)

Comment: I can see one or two other things now.  Please edit the post to add the code to initialize it (`init_genrand64`).

Comment: Use of a large integer seed resulted in the same exception, the value of mti=178.

Comment: ok, the init is at the bottom of the OP.

Comment: I did not notice you were trying to do a 64bit version which explains things like the different tempering. I would get rid of that `On Error` handler and any others so that no errors are masked or handled (so an earlier issue cant reappear as this).  From the description and code, it doesnt seem like it should be happening.  I am not sure `mt` and `mti` as Shared though.

Comment: Since there's truly 312 elements in mt(), and the exception is thrown when mti=354,76,211, etc., I am thinking it's a case of another out-of-range being reported at this line?

Comment: Possibly - thats why I suggested getting rid of any error/exception handlers so you can find the "real" problem (if any).